# Javascript yield generator - how to skip values

Tags: javascript, yield

I've got a collection on items that I'm trying to use yield to create an iterable collection on, but with the added complexity that I want to exclude value that do not match a certain criterion

```
function getNodes()
{
    for each (let node in my_nodes)
    {
        if ( node.cost < 1000 )
            yield node;
    }
}
```

which seemed reasonable and I called it using:

```
let nodes = getNodes();
for (let item in nodes)
{
    ....
```

However, I found that `item` was coming back as undefined, causing the code to barf. Have I got my syntax correct? Is there a better way of doing this? I'd rather not create a pared down version of the original list if I can help it as I was hoping to iterate intelligently over the excluded nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue. Is `getNodes` yielding what you expect?

```
function getX() {
    for each (let x in [1, 2, 3, 4]) {
        yield x;
    }
}
let y = getX();
for (let x in y) {
    console.log(x);
}
// 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Your problem is either in `my_nodes` or that no `node` has a property *cost* `< 1000`.

```
undefined < 1000 // false
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that my problem might be because of the conditional in the generator but removing it hasn't helped. My only other theory is some kind of scoping issue on the objects within `my_nodes` but it is perfectly valid and can be observed in the debugger. I'm going to cut out the use of `yield` completely as I don't really need it in this case and frankly, I don't really like `yield` either - find it quite unintuitive. Thanks again.